# url rewriting everything to index.php except few is not working for a saas application

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using this code in my htaccess file to redirect all requests to index.php and it works.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now, I am trying to redirect few requests to another file `public.php` (i..e load everthing via index.php if user is logged in, otherwise load files via public.php - that's the idea)

I have tried several methods which works for others but none of them seems to be working for me., I have no idea why.

the application structure is

```
[FOLDER]
app
www
static
.htaccess
```

And this is the .htaccess used in the root folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(static.)?website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ static/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.website\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

By default if the subdomain is `www` or `static` files are loaded from `www` and `static` folders respectively. If the url is accessed via some other subdomain then the files are loaded from `app` directory.

## The codes i tried are

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^public$ public.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

interchanged these two lines as well as tried with removing L, QSA

And many others.., As many i could find on Google + Stackoverflow., But none of them worked, `I guess its not working due to how i have coded the .htaccess file in the root directory`.

### If you guys can find any obvious problems with this htaccess codes please let me know how to fix it, No matter how much i try to learn htaccess i always suck at it, If you know of any good tutorial related to this please post its link as well.., I already Googled and read many articles on it already.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but you want to redirect the user to another file when he is logged on? Why not send all trafic to index.php, and check in the first lines weather the user is logged on or not. If logged on, continue, else use PHP header to redirect to another file.

Comment: The way i have developed the application, index.php checks if the user is logged in and only then displays the content, If not logged in then redirects the user to the login page... But since every request is passed via index.php it causes infinite loop as even to load the login page index.php is used and since the user is not logged in... user is redirected to the login page.. hope you get what i mean.. Thats the reason i need few requests to be passed via public.php such that even if the user is not logged in public files can be viewed easily and public.php doesn't need user to be logged in.

Comment: I think the problem is within index.php. Once it is clear the user is not logged in, it should not redirect the user, but just show the login form. In case you do not want to use index.php for login handling, create a new file "login.php" and redirect the user to there. The first htaccess code will detect that login.php is an actual file on the server and will thus not rewrite the user to index.php. If this doesn't work, insight in index.php would be appriciated.

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but it would be easier to use public.php to handle all these as there isn't just login which i want user to access without logging in but other public files as well like login, forgot password, about, etc. Again the same problem.. I can use index.php to display the login page if user is not logged in and I am doing just that, But i want the url to change as well, And if i redirect the user to another url.. this causes url loop as index.php is used to redirect user as well as used to serve the needed file. HTACCESS solution will be perfect for this but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: could you give a couple of "And if i redirect the user to another url.. ", than i shall try creating a htaccess for that.

Comment: Look at the very first htaccess code i have put in my questions, I just want public.php file to be used if there's a public present in the url, If public is not present in the url then all the request should be processed by index.php, Though this is very easy i tried different techniques but none of them worked for me., Try looking at my second htaccess code.., I guess its responsible for making my other htaccess code not work... or kinda like that.

Answer (score 1):

It took a little to reallize what was wrong, but here it is...

```
RewriteEngine On

# first line: If the filename contains public.php, dont rewrite again.
# second line: If the requested URI contains /public, rewrite to public.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/public.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public.php?$1 [L]


# Now here layed the problem, you do NOT want to rewrite the requested URI IF it is pointing to an actual file on the server.
# Thus, a condition for rewriting to index.php, is that the file does not exist.
# The second condition is that the directory does not exist. Not sure you need that though.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$ [L]
```

Thus, the problem with the 3th htaccess, is that "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" is working on the "public" rewrite, but not on index.php as it should.
Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it didn't work., But i added these lines at the end of my second htaccess code (see question) which is actually the first htaccess file and it worked. RewriteRule ^public(.*)$ app/public.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]